# Is there an equivalent of the Rhino Mocks .Do() method in Moq?

Tags: moq, rhino-mocks

Is there an equivalent of the Rhino Mocks `.Do()` method in Moq? I am converting my Rhino Mocks code to Moq, and am stuck on the following:

```
mockedObject
    .Expect(x => x.GetSomething())
    .Do((Func<SomeClass>)(() => new SomeClass());
```

This is not the same as (in Moq, similar in Rhino Mocks):

```
mockedObject
    .Setup(x => x.GetSomething())
    .Return(new SomeClass());
```

When `GetSomething()` is called multiple times in your unit test, the first piece of code will always return a new instance. The second piece will always return the same instance.

What I want is for my mocked object (with Moq) to always return a new instance. So I actually want to provide an implementation of the `GetSomething()` method to my mocked object.

[Using sequences](http://madprops.org/blog/moq-triqs-successive-expectations/) won't do the trick, because I don't know how many times `GetSomething()` will be called, nor am I interested in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to pass `.Returns` a `Func<SomeClass>` just like you're doing with Rhino mocks:

```csharp
mockedObject
    .Setup(x => x.GetSomething())
    .Returns(() => new SomeClass());
```